# TypeError: Type contract InsuranceClaim is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I am confused why the following code is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0

contract InsuranceClaimFactory{
    address public claimer;
    address[] public deployedInsuranceClaim;
    function createInsuranceClaim () public {
        address newInsuranceClaim = new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender);
        deployedInsuranceClaim.push(newInsuranceClaim);
    }

    function getDeployedInsuranceClaims () public view returns (address[] memory){
        return deployedInsuranceClaim;
    }
}
```

The constructor for `InsuranceClaim` is

```
constructor (address creator) public {
claimer=creator;
}
```

The error is

> TypeError: Type contract InsuranceClaim is not implicitly convertible
>   to expected type address

Comment: What behaviour you are expecting with `new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender)`?

Comment: It seems like may be 0.4.99 or greater versions change the syntax of a creating object but in a lower version like `0.4.24` this code runs without error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **ERROR:**  Type contract InsuranceClaim is not implicitly convertible to expected type address means you can not store InsuranceClaim type
> of object in address variable. AS per solidity version [0.5.0
> Documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/) you can define and use `InsuranceClaim` like this:

```
pragma solidity>0.4.99<0.6.0;

contract InsuranceClaimFactory{
    address public claimer;
   
    InsuranceClaim[] public deployedInsuranceClaim;
    function createInsuranceClaim () public {
        InsuranceClaim newInsuranceClaim = new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender);
        deployedInsuranceClaim.push(address(newInsuranceClaim));
    }

    function getDeployedInsuranceClaims () public view returns (InsuranceClaim[] memory){
        return deployedInsuranceClaim;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
address newInsuranceClaim = address(new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender));
```

and it would work fine

Answer (score 0):

```
  function createInsuranceClaim () public {
        // type is InsuranceClaim
        InsuranceClaim newInsuranceClaim = new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender);
        //                     push the address of new contract
        deployedInsuranceClaim.push(address(newInsuranceClaim));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with version >=0.8, you need:

```
InsuranceClaim newInsuranceClaim = new InsuranceClaim(msg.sender);
deployedInsuranceClaim.push(payable(address(newInsuranceClaim)));
```

Note the use of payable here.

Comment: That's only if `deployedInsuranceClaim` were of type `payable[]`. In the question it's just an ordinary address.